# Dynamics CRM mandatory field which appears twice on the form, once hidden once visible

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a form which has two sections, both of which contain a particular field that is "business required". In my current scenario the first of these sections is hidden, while the second is visible. (Basically, which of the two is visible is set in JScript and depends on the value of a drop down list).

The problem is that if the user does not enter a value for the mandatory field and then hits save, the form attempts to validate it on the first of the two occurrences, (i.e. the one that is not visible). When it discovers that the user has not filled this value, it then brings the hidden section into view despite the fact that the same offending field is already in view further down the form.

Is there any way I can stop it doing this, or workaround my issue in another way?

**Edit:**

OK, from the answers below, I think maybe I didn't make the situation clear enough. I don't think setting the field to be non-mandatory, or filling it with a token value, will do the trick because I do want the mandatory status to be validated if the user has not filled in the field.

The issue I'm having is that having validated it, it is showing the user the version of the field that had been hidden, rather than the one that is already visible.

[image: Image depicting the scenario. When the form is validated, the hidden section (shown with red border) appears, because the "Consultant" field is not filled]

As far as I know the simple API, to set the field to mandatory or not, applies equally to any occurrences of that field on the form, not one specific one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: ok this isn't pretty but should work.

You can get at the collection of values using

```
var bothControls = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('transactioncurrencyid').controls
```

And using

```
bothControls.get(1)
```

Gives you the second (zero based index, natch) so you can make it disabled

```
bothControls.get(1).setDisabled(true)
```

Which means validation will be skipped

Comment: Hi glosrob I don't think this will solve it as I do want the field validated,. See edit to the question for clarification.

Comment: Ah yes my mistake, that is interesting - I thought the value was copied to both fields when on the form twice, obviously not.. thinking caps set to 'on'

Comment: It is copied to the other field, I see the problem, sorry having a slow day!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the requirement value:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("FieldName").setRequiredLevel("none");
```

Comment: Hi Pedro I don't think this will solve it as I do want the field validated. See edit to the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can make fields not required by using this call `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("field_tonotbe_required").setRequiredLevel("none");`
But since the field is on the form twice, I'm not sure if the Javscript SDK will make all fields not required, or just the first one, so you may have to walk the hierarchy from the section to find the field and then call `setRequiredLevel` on the exact field you're desiring to change.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to set required level to just one of the instances of the field on the form and not the other?

Comment: I would think so, You're probably going to have to dig into the CRM SDK javascript code (not fun) to figure out what it's doing, and find the attribute that one you want and update it, or possible remove the one you don't...

Comment: Yep, thanks. Glosrob's solution seems to do exactly what you're suggesting so all looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a script that will fire in on change and fill in the entered value from the visible section's field into the hidden section's correspondent?

Suppose that the two business required fields are called *Hubba* and *Bubba*. Connect a JavaScript code to both that on change will check if *Hubba* is empty (and if so, copy over the contents of *Bubba* into it. Otherwise, it will just copy over what's in *Hubba* into *Bubba*.

I'm assuming that the fields are corresponding in their nature, so that you **may** copy over information between them.

I thought of two other options (less optimal IMHO). The first is what Pedro said, enhanced by turning the validation on and off. Not sure if it'd work. I'm just mentioning it for completeness' sake.

The second is to apply process driven UI from Polaris. Really not sure if it'd work but in theory it should.

Comment: Hi, sorry again - the situation probably wasn't clear enough. There aren't two business required fields (Hubba,Bubba) there is just one, but it's shown twice on the form. Thanks for the answer anyway, and it looks like I've solved it through glosrob's solution.